# Files sorting with version number in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have this folder in a directory. With different version on them.

```
CD1,CD2,CD3,CD4,CD5,CD6,CD7,CD8,CD9,CD11,CD12
```

I'm new to powershell, can anyone help me to get the latest version folder from the above folders? Here CD12 is the latest folder. I can't use last modified time because I copy them at the same time.

```
$FolderName=(Get-ChildItem C:\Current\CD |Where-Object {$_.name -like "*CD*"}| sort{$_.name.Substring(2,2)}|Select-Object Name -Last 1).Name)
Write-Host "$FolderName"
```

I tried the above script and it did not help. Can anyone help me?
The next new version is `CD13`, and the script should get that folder

Comment: When you say "get the latest version", do you mean the highest numbered subfolder, or the one with the most recent modification, or some other criteria?

Comment: Yes, the highest numbered folder, in this case its "CD12".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below

```
$max_version = Get-ChildItem "C:\Current\" | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} 
| Foreach-Object {$_.Name} | Foreach-object {$_ -replace "CD", ""} 
| measure -maximum | Select-Object -expand Maximum

Write-host ("CD" + $max_version)
```

Which will result in `CD12`

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it.  When I tried to run your code, I ran into two errors.  First, you have an extra ')' at the end of the line causing a syntax error.  Second, your 'SubString()' call is failing because you're trying to get the 3rd and 4th characters of a string without a 4th character ("CD1").  You don't need the scriptblock to your `Sort` command, though.  You can just sort on the Name field.

```
$FolderName = Get-ChildItem C:\7005\Hot-Fix\CD | where Name -like "CD*" | sort Name | Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Name
```

As a side note, this uses the PowerShell 3 syntax for `Where-Object` and `Sort-Object` to omit the `{}`.  And it uses the `-ExpandProperty` parameter to `Select-Object`, so you don't have to wrap the whole thing in parens to get the Name property.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
#requires -v 3
$baseFolder='C:\7005\Hot-Fix\CD'
$folder=dir $baseFolder\CD* -Directory | 
    ? basename -CMatch 'CD\d{1,}' | 
    sort @{e={'{0:0000}' -f [int]($_ -replace '\D')}} -Descending | 
    select -First 1
```

Notice, I'm considering case sensitive matching; also, `$folder` contains what you're looking for.